# Multiple select queries into a single query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to group multiple select statements into a single query and into multiple columns

I have already tried using UNION but it causes one of my selects to go missing (probably misusing it)

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) AS EMERGENCIA FROM Incidentes WHERE Prioridad_Real = 'Emergencia' AND Estado = 'Resuelto a Tiempo'
AND Fecha_Asigna >= '2013-08-22 13:30:00.000' and Fecha_Resul <= '2013-08-23 11:16:00.000'

SELECT COUNT(*) AS ALTA FROM Incidentes WHERE Prioridad_Real = 'Alta' AND Estado = 'Resuelto a Tiempo' 
AND Fecha_Asigna >= '2013-08-22 13:30:00.000' and Fecha_Resul <= '2013-08-23 11:16:00.000'

SELECT COUNT(*) AS MEDIA FROM Incidentes WHERE Prioridad_Real = 'Media' AND Estado = 'Resuelto a Tiempo'
AND Fecha_Asigna >= '2013-08-22 13:30:00.000' and Fecha_Resul <= '2013-08-23 11:16:00.000'

SELECT COUNT(*) AS BAJA FROM Incidentes WHERE Prioridad_Real = 'Baja' AND Estado = 'Resuelto a Tiempo'
AND Fecha_Asigna >= '2013-08-22 13:30:00.000' and Fecha_Resul <= '2013-08-23 11:16:00.000'
```

**Expected Result:**

[image: Expected result]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using the following query:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Prioridad_Real = 'Emergencia' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as EMERGENCIA,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Prioridad_Real = 'Alta' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as ALTA,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Prioridad_Real = 'Media' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as MEDIA,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Prioridad_Real = 'Baja' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as BAJA
FROM   Incidentes WHERE  Estado = 'Resuelto a Tiempo' 
AND Fecha_Asigna >= '2013-08-22 13:30:00.000' and Fecha_Resul <= '2013-08-23 11:16:00.000'
```